# setState() is not changing visibility

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a pop-up dialog that asks for the user's password when he enters certain screens. This field should have an icon that changes the password visibility, but the state change is not being made, it only happens when I exit the dialog and open it again.

```
  getConfirmationPortalKey() {
return showGeneralDialog(
  transitionBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2, child) => BackdropFilter(
    filter:
        ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 4 * anim1.value, sigmaY: 4 * anim1.value),
    child: FadeTransition(
      child: child,
      opacity: anim1,
    ),
  ),
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: true,
  barrierLabel: '',
  barrierColor: Colors.black26,
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  pageBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2) => AlertDialog(
    content: Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [                    
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Input Password',
                      suffixIconConstraints:
                          BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 50, width: 50),
                      suffixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 24,
                          height: 24,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: passwordPortalVisible
                                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                                    "assets/svgs/icons/visibility_off.svg",
                                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    color: widget.colors.grey.shade400,
                                  )
                                : SvgPicture.asset(
                                    "assets/svgs/icons/visibility_on.svg",
                                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    color: widget.colors.grey.shade400,
                                  ),
                            onPressed: passwordVisible
                                ? null
                                : () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      passwordVisible =
                                          !passwordVisible;
                                    });
                                  },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: textEditingControllerKey,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    obscureText: !passwordVisible,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
    Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                  widget._myBtns.elevatedButton('OK
```

', (){UserLogin user = UserLogin();})
),
],
),
),
),
],
),
);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to use `StatefulBuilder` inside the `AlertDialog`. I think this is because the dialog is an overlay and doesn't know about the widget it came from.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

Below is your code edited:

```dart
 getConfirmationPortalKey() {
return showGeneralDialog(
  transitionBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2, child) => BackdropFilter(
    filter:
        ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 4 * anim1.value, sigmaY: 4 * anim1.value),
    child: FadeTransition(
      child: child,
      opacity: anim1,
    ),
  ),
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: true,
  barrierLabel: '',
  barrierColor: Colors.black26,
  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  pageBuilder: (ctx, anim1, anim2) => AlertDialog(
    content: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setDialogState) {

          bool passwordVisible = false;
 
         return Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [                    
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Input Password',
                      suffixIconConstraints:
                          BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 50, width: 50),
                      suffixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 24,
                          height: 24,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: passwordPortalVisible
                                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                                    "assets/svgs/icons/visibility_off.svg",
                                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    color: widget.colors.grey.shade400,
                                  )
                                : SvgPicture.asset(
                                    "assets/svgs/icons/visibility_on.svg",
                                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                    color: widget.colors.grey.shade400,
                                  ),
                            onPressed:() => setDialogState(() {
                                      passwordVisible =
                                          !passwordVisible;
                                    });
                                 
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: textEditingControllerKey,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    obscureText: !passwordVisible,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
    Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                  widget._myBtns.elevatedButton('OK
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in 'onPressed'. This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: sorry, my bad, change onPressed to `() => setDialogState ...`. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
onPressed: passwordVisible ? null : () {...}
```

Your onPressed event only calls the function if `passwordVisible` is false. Remove the ternary operator and it will call whether `passwordVisible` is true or false:

```
onPressed: () {...}
```

Comment: Did not work. I did it like this: onPressed: passwordVisible ? null : () {setState(() {passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;});},

Comment: That's still the same problem, try `onPressed: () {...}` (Without the ternary operator checking passwordVisible)